# How to show widgets on pages in Flask?

Tags: python, templates, flask, widget, jinja2

How can I create a widget on the site, such as login forms, dynamic menu (items taken from the database), site statistics?

I know that you can render a template that will extend out of a base template. And in the base template you can create these widgets.

But I do not know how to move the logic from the base template to my code. For example, the selection data for the block. Such actions certainly can be done in the template, but it would be a poor method in my opinion.

Sorry for my bad English. If you can not understand, I'll try to rephrase.

Comment: I found [Context Processors](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/templating/). It seems that I need. Is it right to use it?

Comment: If you want these values to always be available in every template you render then yes, absolutely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would use a python library called [WTForms](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/1.0.1/). It helps you write code for creating forms and other widgets backed by database which you can render using jinja2 templates.

```
    class YourForm(Form):
         your_field1 = TextField()
         ....
         your_fieldn = SubmitField()


   @app.route('/')
   def view():
       form=YourForm()
       return render_template('your.html', form=form)

   In your.html
   <form >
     {{ form.your_field1 }}
     ....
     {{ form.your_fieldn }}
   </form>
```

Check out this flask pattern for [form validation and rendering](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/wtforms/) to know more about it.

Edit: To create global variables available to all templates,there are two ways:

1. You can use [global dict of jinja environment](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/api/#the-global-namespace).
   This is the code:

   ```
      app.jinja_env.globals.update({'variable':1})
   ```
2. You can use [ContextProcessor](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/templating/#context-processors). Code:

   ```
   @app.context_processor
   def inject_variable():
       return dict(variable=1)
   ```

Now you can access `variable` in any template of your app.

Comment: Thank you. I'll see WTForms. But your code is not quite what I need. I would like to avoid adding widgets context to the template in each view.

Comment: @Ticksy Are you talking about global widgets? So that you define them at one place and they are automatically available to the templates?